# how to get grouping references [1-4] in wiley template

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

```
\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\setcitestyle{square}
\articletype{Article Type}
\makeatletter
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I am applying `\cite{1,2,3,4}` and getting [1,2,3,4].
But I want [1-4]. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Does the related links on the right help?

Comment: Same question as last time: Is `WileyNJD-v2` available somewhere? Where can we download it?

Comment: Try adding `sort&compress` to the class options, i.e.     `\documentclass[sort&compress,AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}`.

Answer (score 3):

As `WileyNJD-v2.cls` uses `natbib` (or a custom version of `natbib` distributed with the class), you can use the `sort&compress` option for `natbib` to do what you're asking. Add it to the class options, and it's picked up by the package:

```
\documentclass[sort&compress,AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
```